# Simple C# goto alternative

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms

I heard goto is bad, so I ask someone in this site if my code is better using goto or other alternative

```
    public FormMain()
    {
    // start of the apps
    Start:

        // show login form
        FormLogin login = new FormLogin();
        DialogResult dr = login.ShowDialog();

        // cancel form loading if login form is canceled
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Load += (s, e) => Close();
            return;
        }

        // login error
        if (dr == DialogResult.No)
        {
            // back to start
            goto Start;
        }

        // Initialize main form component
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use goto in this case. Use a loop instead, like this:

```
public FormMain()
{
    DialogResult dr;
    do
    {
        // show login form
        FormLogin login = new FormLogin();
        dr = login.ShowDialog();

        // cancel form loading if login form is canceled
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Load += (s, e) => Close();
            return;
        }
    }
    while(dr == DialogResult.No); // login error

    // Initialize main form component
    InitializeComponent();
}
```